# CSS cross-browser positioning of form elements

Tags: css, html, forms, cross-browser, position

Has anyone come up with a strategy for styling form elements that works cross-browser? For me, `textfields` and `textareas` are usually not a problem, but `checkboxes`, `radio buttons`, and `selects` (dropdowns) create havoc.

I don't need these things to look identical in the various browsers. But I'd like to be able to line them up predictably. I'd like to be able to put a `checkbox` below a `textfield` and have it line up with the left edge of the `textfield`. If this works in `Safari`, then it doesn't in `Firefox`: there the `checkbox` ends up below the center of the `textfield`.  Sometimes the vertical placement can differ by `48px` or more.

I have Opera on my Apple `iMac`, on my PC desktop computer with `Windows XP Pro`, and on a PC laptop with `Windows 7` (in each case, the newest version of `Opera`). In order to position the `checkboxes` I had to individually target each of these machines.

`Select` fields (dropdowns) give me the same headaches. Often they're okay in some browsers, but on others they end up on top of a `checkbox` or `textfield`, or `60px` to the left or right.

The one thing I really haven't tried is `CSS` reset, since Eric Meyer has said he doesn't use it for forms. Has anyone else tried it with success? Is there any reliable way to build a form with generally uniform styling? I don't even mind identifying the user agent and delivering specific `CSS`. But when the same browsers render the elements differently on computers of different screen size, the problem becomes overwhelming.

Yet clearly there's an answer, because a lot of forms on the web seem to work cross-browser. Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: Cutting your question down to the point will help you get answers.

Comment: Hm, I don't normally have problems with this. If you post an example, perhaps we can suggest sommat.

Comment: This is a problem for all of us for sure. I suggest you try out some reset patterns. AND make a reset - for this. you can use codepen or something and have it open on all machines at once and tweak. Making elements display: inline-block; can be a useful thing because then you can vertical-align: center; them. Good luck! Responsive forms are their own issues well. Look into -webkit-appearance: none; - for iOS devices too. Submit buttons need to be overridden with background: color; vs. background-color: - etc... lots of tricky things - I'm trying to get them normalized myself. Good luck!

Comment: Post your findings! (-:

Answer (score 0):

The Basic idea for customizing the form elements for better UI of it is **not 100% accurate** in css, it is because the form elements styling depends upon the OS in the system, it embeds the default css of the OS for the browser...

For instance, the **radio button, checkboxs, selects, input, textarea** they all fetches default css of OS depends upon the browser...

Their is no solution but a making a different UI for the form element with jquery. Like i am currently on [Jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) framework, this is Touch-Optimized Web for mobile and tablets. They have customized the whole UI for the form element with divs, spans, anchors etc with jquery and css3...

Refer:-
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/forms/

Form structure in html:-

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Radio buttons, vertical controlgroup:</legend>
        <input name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
</fieldset>
```

Form structure showing on browser:-

```
<div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">
  <div class="ui-radio">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" name="radio-choice-1">
    <label for="radio-choice-1" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="radio-on" data-theme="c" data-mini="false" class="ui-radio-on ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-first-child ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Cat</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-on ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="choice-2" id="radio-choice-2" name="radio-choice-1">
    <label for="radio-choice-2" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="radio-off" data-theme="c" data-mini="false" class="ui-radio-off ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Dog</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="choice-3" id="radio-choice-3" name="radio-choice-1">
    <label for="radio-choice-3" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="radio-off" data-theme="c" data-mini="false" class="ui-radio-off ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Hamster</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="choice-4" id="radio-choice-4" name="radio-choice-1">
    <label for="radio-choice-4" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="radio-off" data-theme="c" data-mini="false" class="ui-radio-off ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-last-child ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Lizard</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The UI change by jquery and css3 for better looking UI what i am trying to say, simply take this as example to understand whats the idea behind the issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Checkbox and radio buttons **can't** be positioned (vertically) with their labels cross-browser. You've to rely on some proprietary or CSS hack stuff.
  That's not as bad as it could appear: I despise using CSS hacks for layout but for translating 1px vertically a button on some browser: who seriously cares if another browser is falsely targeted and a radio button is moved 1px?
- You still can custom the style of these form elements. The most accessible way I could find is here: http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/customInput/
  Radio and checkbox are hidden under the background images of the labels. With or without CSS and images, it still works as well as in screen readers.
- I don't use CSS resets (overkill for my use, just [Knacss](http://www.knacss.com/) which is very light on purpose) and for forms I use the very good work of isellsoap 
  [**forms.css** - Consistent looking forms across all major browsers](http://isellsoap.github.io/forms.css/).
  I tried to remove each single line of their CSS and that's how I understood how f**up modern browsers are when it comes to forms. The gold medal goes to Chrome, when you understand that nothing else than `-webkit-appearance: none` will let you style anything and that from here you've to rebuild everything from scratch (well, isellsoap did that hard work).
- If you want to align vertically on the same line a label and an input[type="text"], then stick to `vertical-align: middle`. Browser and CSS will take care of alignments for you... `top` value is the beginning of the need of a different padding on each element you'll encounter. Still necessary if a label goes on two lines for example.

EDIT: I've never seen a 48px-misplacement or 60px on left/right (except with absolute positioning on IE6/7 and its buggy behaviour). Do you've a fiddle for this and the precise browser+OS combination where it can be seen?

Answer (score 0):

user agents typically render form controls differently, something i think that dom shadow and web components api is going to fix for us....at the moment you have a plethora of libs that style controls cross-browser...but the end all is formalize.css; it supports ie6+ and the other big 4 browsers out the box, and it also provides support for five js libs, whereas 99% of these solutions are jQuery only. formalize.css is the bomb. http://formalize.me/

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete css for form fields cross browser test

```
form, fieldset, legend {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    line-height:normal;
}    
input[type="checkbox"] { 
    -moz-appearance: checkbox; -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    margin-left:3px; border:0; 
    vertical-align: middle;    
    top: -1px;bottom: 1px;
    *overflow: hidden;}
input[type="radio"] { -moz-appearance: radio; -webkit-appearance: radio; }
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
input, button, textarea, select {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color:#000000;
    font-size: 100%; /* for IE */
    padding:6px;
    margin:5px 0;
    border-radius:4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    *border-radius:4px; 
    -border-radius:4px; 
    border-radius:4px/8;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    background:#fff;        
    text-transform:capitalize;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-appearance: none; -webkit-appearance: none;*/
}
input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {

    color:#fff; font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
}
button, input[type="submit"], input[type="image"], 
label > input[type="checkbox"]  {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */  
    *height: 13px; /* Removes excess padding in IE 7 */
    *width: 13px;
    backgorund: #fff; 
}
input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="password"]:focus, 
input[type="email"]:focus, 
textarea:focus, select:focus { outline:0;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner, button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; }
textarea {      
    resize:none;
    overflow: auto; /* Removes default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9 */
    vertical-align: top; /* Improves readability and alignment in all browsers */
} 

/* placeholder and tooltip styles */
*::-webkit-input-placeholder, /* WebKit browsers */
*:-moz-placeholder, /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
*::-moz-placeholder, /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
*:-ms-input-placeholder /* Internet Explorer 10+ */ {
color: #999; 
}

[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
[placeholder]:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }


/* mantatory field  styles */
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message {
  padding: 1em;
}
```